# elasticsearch copy data from ec2 to local windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Already too much of snapshot and restore over internet..!! my basic problem is:
My test environment is on EC2. For the dev team we have a local box to which developers connect and do the testing. Unluckily this local box crashed and we don't have any local data to test.

The next thing was to create a copy of EC2 and using that create the local box again.

Steps taken:
1.) Create snapshot on S3.
2.) Downloaded the snapshot on my windows box.

Problem statement:
How can I use this snapshot to restore the data on windows box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answers are there on internet but it's tough to find the proper process. And it goes like this:

I have a snapshot on S3 of one of my instances. Problem statement was to use this S3 snapshot to restore the data on a newly created instance of elasticsearch(can be anywhere: windows/EC2 etc.)

First and formost thing is to create a repository on the new instance. This repository has to be same as the one from which snapshot is created. In my case, the repository was created from EC2 instance on S3. On new instance, same repository has to be created. Now this repository will be pointing to the S3 repository which was created from EC2. Next is a simple restore on the new instance. Note that prefer restoring a specific index which is required. I had tough time resolving the issue created from Kibana snapshots as well. Any one facing any other issues can discuss here in this thread further.